# different sized bins in matlab

Tags: matlab, bins

In **Matlab** I have a vector *Muen* which I want to reduce in size by dividing it in to different length bins. The vector has a few values that need high accuracy bins and a lot of values that are roughly equal and could be collected into bins with size of up to a few hundred values.
I also need to know the index for all old bins going into a new bin in order to shorten a sencod vector *fluence*.

The goal is to speed up a summation of two vectors sum(*fluence*.**Muen*) by using different sized bins determined by *Meun* and do the sum of *fluence* into the new bins before the vector multiplication.
For this I try to use

```
edges=[min(Muen):0.0001:Muen(13),Muen(12:-1:1)); 
[N,bin]=histc(*Muen*,edges)
```

The problem is how to make the vector *edges*, as there is a large difference between the maximum and minimum of *Muen* and a small difference between other values. Is there a way to make the steps of *edges* depending on the derivative *Muen*?

In order to get the shorter version of *Muen* would be something like

```
MuenShort=N.*edges;
```

but it did not work quit right (could be  a fault in *edges*), any suggestions?

I also do not really get how *bin* gives the index of the values that go into the new bins?

clarification:
what I want to do is from a vector *m* or *Muen* take the elements that are roughly equal and replace the with one element and at the same time keeping track of the index for which element goes into a new vector *n* or *MuenShort*. example
{m1}->n1,(1), {m2}->n2,(2), {m3,m4}-> m3=m4=n3,(3,4),{m5,m6,m7,m8}-> m5=m6=m7=m8=n4,{5,6,7,8}...
   where n1>>n2 but the difference between n3 and n4 might not be so large. the number of m-elements in each n-element should be determined by the number of m-elements that are roughly equal to each other, or rather lies between two limits. So the bin size should vary between one element to a few hundred elements.
Then I want to use indexes to make the *fluence* vector shorter

> > fluenceShort(1:length(MuenShort))=  [sum(fluence(1)),sum(fluence(2)),sum(fluence(3,4)),sum(fluence(5,6,7,8))...];
> >     goal=sum(fluenceShort.*MuenShort)

Is there a way to implement this in Matlab?

Comment: Please make your question more clear. You are talking about bins and using histc, so you probably want to calculate some histogram, but you never say so. And is `Muen` sorted decreasingly? Since you seem to use it backwards to create your edges ...

Answer (score 1):

Even if I don't understand your question clearly, I would suggest this. Perhaps you could sort your vector `muen`, pick a fixed number `n`, and define each bin so that it contains exactly `n` values of `muen`. For simplicity, the length of `muen` is assumed to be a multiple of `n`:

```
n = 10;
m = length(muen_sorted)/n; 
muen_sorted = sort(muen);
edges = [-inf mean([muen_sorted(n:n:end-1); muen_sorted(n+1:n:end)]) inf ];
muen_short = mean(reshape(muen_sorted,n,m));
```

Note that `m+1` edges (vector `edges`) are obtained, corresponding to `m` bins. Bin edges lie exactly between the closest values of neighbouring bins. Thus, the upper edge of the first bin is `(muen_sorted(n)+muen_sorted(n+1)/2`; the upper edge of the next bin is `(muen_sorted(2*n)+muen_sorted(2*n+1)/2`, and so on.

The "representative value" of each bin (vector `muen_short`) is computed as the `mean` of the values that lie in that bin. Or perhaps the `median` would make more sense, depending on your application.

As a result of this code, `muen_short(1)` is the value corresponding to the bin with edges `edge(1)` and `edge(2)`; `muen_short(2)` is the value corresponding to the bin with edges `edge(2)` and `edge(3)`, etc.

You can now use the variable `edges` to build the histogram of `fluence` with those same edges.

Comment: One aspect of this problem that I don't fully understand is how you are going to keep track of what element ended up in which bin, so that later fluence is binned correctly as well. I suppose that requires that fluence be a linear (or at least monotonic) function of Muen?